# Wait several seconds in loop after colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made this script for checking collisions betweenn player and a trap and removing players hp. It work perfectly, but hp is decreasing nearly instantly. I tried to use coroutines but I've got no clue how to make it work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class hp_loss : MonoBehaviour 

{

public float loss_hp = 1;


    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        GameObject gObj = other.gameObject;

        if (gObj.CompareTag("enemy") && hajs.hp > 0)
        {
            hajs.hp = hajs.hp - loss_hp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something in this manner

```
 float timer = 0;
 bool timerCheck = false;
 float timerThreshold = 1000; // value you want to wait

 void Update()
 {
     if(timerCheck)
     {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
     }
     if (timer > timerThreshold)
     {
        timer = 0;
        GameObject gObj = ...; // get player game object using GameObject.FindWithTag for example

        if (gObj.CompareTag("enemy") && hajs.hp > 0)
        {
            hajs.hp = hajs.hp - loss_hp;
        }
     }
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D col)
 {
    timerCheck = true;
 }

 void OnCollisionExit2D(Collider2D col)
 {
    timerCheck = false;
 }
```

Comment: Works great. I slightly have modified that but idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

I doubt you want `OnTriggerStay2D`, as it will fire multiple times.

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        GameObject gObj = other.gameObject;

        if (gObj.CompareTag("enemy") && hajs.hp > 0)
        {
            hajs.hp = hajs.hp - loss_hp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After i putted this in while loop it worked perfectly but hp decreased also after collision (I mean when i walked away from trap). Without loop it decreased hp once. I tried use "OnTriggerStay2D" function but then hp were removed instantly.

Comment: @MiszczTheMaste it will decrease after you walk away from trap because 2 seconds wait is probably too long. Once player enters trigger this code fires in main part after 2 seconds no matter if player goes away from trap. Hard to tell what you want, if you just want to use wait because trap has animation or something, then set the time to equal animation length. You dont need while loop. Use the other answers if you want multiple hp drops in the trap

Answer (score 0):

greendhsde's answer should do the work but just in-case you want to do all of these in the `OnTriggerStay2D` function without making more functions and with less code, this code should be fine too. The higher the `decreaseTime`, the less time it updates. If `decreaseTime` is set to 2 seconds, it will update every 2 seconds.

```
float decreaseTime = 0.2f;
float startCounter = 0f;
public float loss_hp = 1;

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    //Dont decrease if  startCounter < decrease Time
    if (startCounter < decreaseTime)
    {
     startCounter += Time.deltaTime;
     return;
    }
    startCounter = 0; //Reset to 0

     //Don't decrease if score is less or equals to 0
    if (hajs.hp <=0)
    {
       return;
    }

    GameObject gObj = other.gameObject;
    if (gObj.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {

        hajs.hp = hajs.hp - loss_hp;
    }
}
```

Comment: It work in weird way. When player collides with trap hp will decrease by few points and then stops until player will move and then again same thing.

Comment: Modified it. Moved some code outside the compareTag and you not have any other problems.